# strtotime to date returns false

Tags: php, datetime

I have this set of unix timestamps:

1. `1473804000 1471831200`

I'm not able to assign a date in this format `('Y-m-d H:i:s')` to each unix timestamp.

My code:

```
$eventhour = '1473804000';
$client = array(
                'pt' => $pt,
                'eventhour' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $eventhour),
                'activepower' => $avg['system.avg(activepower)']
            );
```

The `eventhour` key is empty, I guess the function `date` returned false. The unix timestamp is valid, why is it returning false?

**My Loop code**

```
foreach ($result as $row):
        $pt = $row['pt'];

        $statement = new \Cassandra\SimpleStatement("select avg(activepower) FROM datavalue_test_by_hour WHERE pt= :pt AND eventhour = :eventhour;");
        $options = new \Cassandra\ExecutionOptions(
            array('arguments' => array('pt' => $pt, 'eventhour' => $row['eventhour'])))
        ;
        $data = $this->cassandra->executeWithOptions($statement, $options);
        $eventhour = $row['eventhour'];
        echo $eventhour . PHP_EOL;
        $avg = $data->first();
        $client = array(
            'pt' => $pt,
            'eventhour' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $eventhour),
            'activepower' => $avg['system.avg(activepower)']
        );
        print_r($client);
        //fputcsv($fp, $client);
    endforeach;
```

**My print_r():**

```
1462554000
Array
(
    [pt] => AFH0AEFB0BFDEI
    [eventhour] => 
    [activepower] => 0.02475
)
1474887600
Array
(
    [pt] => A0A0AEAF0DI0H0
    [eventhour] => 
    [activepower] => 0.1115
)
1475244000
Array
(
    [pt] => AFH0ADE0AB0GDI
    [eventhour] => 
    [activepower] => 0.0905
)
1473008400
Array
(
    [pt] => A0A0AEAF0GDFHB
    [eventhour] => 
    [activepower] => 0.014
)
1470693600
Array
(
    [pt] => AFH0AEE00AF0FG
    [eventhour] => 
    [activepower] => 0.051
)
1452200400
Array
(
    [pt] => AFH0AEE00BACIC
    [eventhour] => 
    [activepower] => 0.152
)
1463637600
Array
(
    [pt] => AFH0ACFB00CD0F
    [eventhour] => 
    [activepower] => 0.041
)
```

Comment: $eventhour is not defined anywhere in the code you posted

Comment: is $eventhour = 1473804000  ?

Comment: yes it is! i will edit the question!

Comment: The code looks good. Tell us how are you accessing the value ?

Comment: I have tried myself and it works for me. Can you post a reproducible sample that doesn't rely on any external variables?

Comment: The timestamp is stored in the database as a bigint and the query is returning it. I echo the return value and is good. Don't understand. :/

Comment: I am asking you again, how are you trying to print the `eventhour` value ?. How do you know that it's empty ? Did you try `print_r($client)` ? That should contain all the values. You can print the individual by `echo $client['eventhour'];`

Comment: I will edit the question and add more input Nandan

Comment: Looks strange, try passing it like this `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1470693600')`

Comment: That worked Nandan. But it's resolved now... :) i had to cast the variable `$eventhour` to a int. Thank you all!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by casting the returned `$row['eventhour']` from the database to a **INT**.

```
$eventhour = (int) $row['eventhour'];
```

Is working now.